# Use require-config.js to load files needed on all pages

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I know how to use `require-config.js` in custom theme, but I would like to use custom javascript file (`myfile.js`) on all pages. In which directory should I add `require-config.js` and how to use it, so that it will work as it should?

Please, don't reference to Magento Official page.

Comment: You can directly call js inside layout xml head tag and you got js in each page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I would like to use require-config and load files with it, not like in Magento 1?

Comment: Its also support in magento 2 you can check module-theme folder layout/default_head_block.xml file

Comment: Yes, i know. But, I want to use require-config.js the correct way.

Answer (score 17):

**`requirejs-config.js` uses for creating the JavaScript resources mapping**. We can find all require configs under: `pub/static/_requirejs`.

As far as I know, the correct way to load our custom script via Require Js: **using template to call our script**. We will create new template with `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` its block class.

If we want to load js files on all pages and don't want to create a new module, our block should reference to **`before.body.end` or `after.body.start container`** in `default.xml` - Magento Theme module.

[image]

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.js" template="Magento_Theme::custom_js.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>

</page>
```

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customScript:'Magento_Theme/js/customscript'
        }
    }
};
```

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/web/js/customscript.js*

```
define('jquery', function($) {

    //Your code here
    //alert('Here');

    }(jQuery)
);
```

Our template will call our script: *app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/custom_js.phtml*

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
    require([
        'jquery',
        'customScript'
    ], function ($, script) {
        //Your code here
        //alert('Here');
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Clear Magento Cache and run static content deploy: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: I call my script on `\app\design\frontend\Enim\blank\Magento_CatalogWidget\templates\product\widget\content\grid.phtml`, but I have requirejs-config.js and script in Theme folder (app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/requirejs-config.js). Is this ok? The problem is that I call my script from multiple different places.

Comment: Your script only affects when the template `templa‌​tes\product\widget\c‌​ontent\grid.phtml` is called.

Comment: Yes, that's ok - the problem is with that one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149019/problem-with-loading-javascript-in-magento-2-from-history, I am wondering if this issue is somehow connected to requirejs call.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I am a little confused by this. I haven't properly tested yet, but am I right in thinking that the function in `custom_js.phtml` is treated as a regular callback, performed after execution of the code contained within `customscript.js`? Or would I need to execute the code declared in `customscript.js` from within the function in `custom_js.phtml`?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I'm also wondering why Iveta's answer states that your `after.body.start` should be changed to `before.body.end`?

Answer (score 7):

Requirejs-config file:
**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
         'myfile': "Vendor_Modulename/js/myfile"
      },   
    shim: {
    'myfile': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
}
```

Your js file should be in: **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/myfile.js**

Now you can use anywhere in your template file by calling the below method:

```
<script>
 require(["jquery","myfile"],function($,myfile){
     $(document).ready(function(){
        //call your js here...
     })
 })
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I asked if anyone knows how to use it in Theme folder, not depending on Module - it should be loaded across the page, not only on one module.

Comment: you can use it in theme folder as well, just call above script and you can use your js

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue

Comment: It works, thanks. But still, I am having issues on some other thing: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149019/problem-with-loading-javascript-in-magento-2-from-history

Comment: Hi, Please let me know where to  place1st step file?

Comment: Works like a charm for custom module js.

Answer (score 7):

There is a easier version using `deps`. Dependencies in the **requirejs-config.js** will load your file when loading requirejs itself (everywhere in the shop). Here is an example of how your **requirejs-config.js** should look:

```
var config = {
    // When load 'requirejs' always load the following files also
    deps: [
        'common-js'
    ],

    // Library file path.
    paths: {
        'common-js': 'js/Your-File-Name'
    },

    // The rest of your config file ...
```

Comment: This is the best solution by far. Clean, concise and great for external resources!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach to Khoa's recommendation, which is excellent Magento dev practice, you can paste your JavaScript in a .phtml file like this:

```
<srcipt>
require(["jquery"],function($){
 $(document).ready(function(){
    your script here...
 })
});
</script>
```

Then link your phtml file from default.xml as described in Khoa's answer, though I would recommend to add it to before.body.end. And, then call your JS script from within **copyright.phtml**, like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
..call your script here ..
});
</script>
```

copyright.phtml gets loaded on every page, even on pages like checkout, where the footer is omitted.