# Problem with loading Javascript in Magento 2 from history

Tags: magento2, javascript, cache

On our Magento 2 new webstore there is a problem with loading javascript from history (with `F5` or new tab). This problem occurs mostly in Microsoft Edge Browser. Sometimes, my code loads fine, but mostly not. If I want it to load as it should, I have to delete browser cache and cookies or `CTRL+F5`. The code that should load is inside:

```
<script>
// <![CDATA[
    requirejs([
        'jquery',
        'cycle2',
        'cycle2carousel'
    ], function ($) {
        $(window).on('load', function() {
           //my code
    });
});
// ]]>
```

I put a debugger point inside, but it never comes to that point. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Your site stills changing? Or sometimes, when loading the browser, you meet this issue?

Comment: No, the site is online. Sometimes, when loading the browser, but when opening the page from history.

Comment: The same issue with Chrome and Firefox? The most js scripts did not load or only your custom script above?

Comment: I can't see the same issue in other browsers, only in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: The most js scripts did not load or only your custom script above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49661/discussion-between-anitr-and-khoa-truongdinh).