# Magento 2, Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Tags: magento2, jquery, ui

I don't get why adding my custom js file causes below issue. Please help understand the cause. Let me know if more details should be provided here.

Is it dependency issue?

[image]

edit: My requirejs-config.js in module

```
var config = {
    "paths":
    {
        "jQueryCustom": "myVendor_myModule/js/jquery.custom",
        "jqueryNoConflict": "myVendor_myModule/js/jquery.no-conflict",
    }
};
```

My jquery.no-conflict.js in module

```
define(['jQueryCustom'],function ()
{
    return jQuery.noConflict(true);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom js you just need to add `jquery/ui` in require section and it will work.

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
    alert('Test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it is a jquery conflict issue. Call a custom js via requirejs-config.js instead of xml or phtml file.

Refer below links for using requirejs-config.js

[Use require-config.js to load files needed on all pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148985/use-require-config-js-to-load-files-needed-on-all-pages)

Hope it will works.

Comment: Actually I'm adding the js file through requirejs-config.js in my module and calling it in my custom theme phtml file, but I'll check the details with the link you provided... keep here updated

Comment: please do static-content deploy and clear cache and then check. It may works.

Comment: I did several times... may you check the edit part, I provided more info. Tnx

Comment: your code should look like this `require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
alert('Test');
});`

Comment: if you js file you need to include `jquery/ui` by adding argument in require in your custom js file.

Comment: @AmanAlam, tnx ..Make it as answer then I accept it

Answer (score 0):

calling the js is incorrect. Please define the js like this in phtml

```
require(['jquery','jQueryCustom'], function($){

// custom codel

 }
```

Comment: That's my jquery.no-conflict.js not the one in phtml file