# jquery issue when page loads

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs, console

I am seeing a jQuery error in the console when the page loads. i have tried [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187632/magento-2-cannot-read-property-ui-of-undefined/187642), but the issue has not been resolved

[image]

i do know where it comes from.when i refresh the page the issue is resolved.

anyone have idea about this?

Comment: This is a classic `require js` issue. To debug it though, could you post the code you are using that is kicking an error? if you have already added in a `require` to the code, it might just be a syntax error.

Comment: @circlesix i have added my script.could you please tell me where i have made an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which i am using in phtml file

```
<script>  
  require(
        ['jquery','Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal','jquery/ui','Company_Custom/js/jquery.cookie'],
        function($, modal) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                modalClass: 'store_cookie_popup'
            };
            if(!$.cookie("warehouse_id")){
                var popup = modal(options, $('#popup_content'));
                $("#popup_content").modal("openModal");
            }
            $('.store_cookie_popup .action-close').click(function(event) {
                $('#ajaxloader').css('display','none');
                $('.loader-overlay').css('display','none');
                $('.loader-overlay.active').css('display','none');
                $('.page-wrapper').css('opacity','1');
                $('.detect').trigger('click');
            });
            $('.store_cookie_popup .nearmarker_store').on('click',function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('key');
                $.cookie("warehouse_id", id);
                window.location.href = "http://192.168.1.157/module/";
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```