# Js script doesn't work

Tags: magento2

I created module that include this view:

```
<form class="add-to-cart-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('testTask/index/AddToCart')?>">
    <input title="sku" class="sku-area" name="sku" type="text">
    <input type="button" class="add-to-cart-button" value="Add to cart">
</form>
```

My layout:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="task" template="Amt_TestTask::firstTask.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I was creating js file, that include ajax query:

(app/code/Amt/TestTask/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js)

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        var form = $('.add-to-cart-form');
        var url = form.attr('action');

        $(document).on('click', '.add-to-cart-button', function () {
            var param = form.serialize();
            alert(param);
            $.ajax({
                showLoader: true,
                url: url,
                data: param,
                type: "POST"
            }).done(function (data) {

            });
        })
    };

});
```

And I added requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom: "Amt_TestTask/js/custom"
        }
    }
};
```

Develop mode is enable. This file was adding in static directory.

```
pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Amt_TestTask/js
```

I know, that i can create link to this js file in layout. 
Like that: `<script src="Webkul_Grid::js/grid.js"/>`
but I think, that it must work without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app/code/Amt/TestTask/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function ajaxy() {
        var form = $('.add-to-cart-form');
        var url = form.attr('action');

        $(document).on('click', '.add-to-cart-button', function () {
            var param = form.serialize();
            alert(param);
            $.ajax({
                showLoader: true,
                url: url,
                data: param,
                type: "POST"
            }).done(function (data) {

            });
        })
    };

});
```

Now you need to call your function in your phtml like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'custom'], function($, ajaxy) {
        ajaxy();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow either this [link](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/custom-javascript-in-magento-2-with-requirejs/)  or this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148985/use-require-config-js-to-load-files-needed-on-all-pages).

**Note:** Don't forget to run below commands --

```
rm -rf var/cache/* generated/*

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

1) in the template, do not use $this, you need to use **$block**.

2) You did not show your controller and routes.xml, I think the problem is in the capital letters, the path must be `frontName/Controller/Action`.

I think you are mistaken with `Index`.

```
action="<?= $block->getUrl('frontName/Controller/Action')?>"
```

Comment: I think, that response is 404, if url is irregular

Comment: But this event doesn’t work